# unit test using typescript and karma

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, amd

I am using karma, jasmine, typescript to write unit test for the helloworld application from https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html.

Below is the test code:

```
///<reference path="../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>

import {
    MyAppComponent
} from '../spray1';

describe("name is Alice", () => {
    var comp = new MyAppComponent();

    it("verify name", () => {
        expect(comp.name).toBe("Alice"); 
    });
});
```

tsc (with "--module commonjs") transpiles this test code into:

```
///<reference path="../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
var spray1_1 = require('../spray1');
describe("name is Alice", function () {
    var comp = new myAppComponent_1.MyAppComponent();
    it("verify name", function () {
        expect(comp.name).toBe("Alice");
    });
});
```

karma fails to run the unit test:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "../myAppComponent" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
>     http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
>     at /Users/spray1/web2/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
>
> Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)

If I use tsc with "--module amd", the transpiled test code is:

```
define(["require", "exports", '../spray1'], function (require, exports, spray1_1) {
    describe("name is Alice", function () {
        var comp = new spray1_1.MyAppComponent();
        it("verify name", function () {
            expect(comp.name).toBe("Alice");
        });
    });
});
```

"karma start test/karma.conf.js" threw below error on the transpiled js files:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, spray1_1) {
>           describe("name is Alice", function () {
>               var comp = new spray1_1.MyAppComponent();
>               it("verify name", function () {
>                   expect(comp.name).toBe("Alice");
>               });
>           });
>       }
>       http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
>       at /Users/spray1/web2/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
>   Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.04 secs / 0 secs)

As you see, I have trouble to make it work either way (--module commonjs/amd). Which way is the right way to go and how to make it work? Appreciate any help!

Comment: How are you referencing the files? Are you using multiple script tags?

Comment: use gulp for compiling and running typescript and their respective testcase. Read https://medium.com/@bojzi/anatomy-of-a-large-angular-application-f098e5e36994#.mmfb9jtml for more info.

Answer (score 1):

So, the link you've provided is to the JavaScript version of the quickstart, but it appears you're using TypeScript.

I would suggest looking at the [TypeScript version of the quickstart documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). It has a `tsconfig.json` file which provides the appropriate compile target:

> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "target": "es5",
>     "module": "system",
>     "moduleResolution": "node",
>     "sourceMap": true,
>     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
>     "experimentalDecorators": true,
>     "removeComments": false,
>     "noImplicitAny": false
>   },
>   "exclude": [
>     "node_modules",
>     "typings/main",
>     "typings/main.d.ts"
>   ]
> }
> ```